# Is it possible to deploy and debug Java application in GKE cluster from Eclipse using JKube?

Tags: java, google-kubernetes-engine, remote-debugging, jkube

Using Eclipse JKube (https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/) ,is it possible to deploy Java application to GKE cluster from the Eclipse IDE itself and perform remote debug ?
I can see some post on Openshift deployment (https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/13/deploy-java-application-red-hat-openshift-using-jkube#how_jkube_helps_build_and_deploy_java_applications ) but not for Azure,AWS or GCP. .

Comment: Refer this [blog](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin/) helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. adding the debug port as a port you want to expose in jkube
2. make sure the entrypoint contains the java command with your debug config

Applying this should create a container which has an additional port for your debugger to connect to and a command that starts the app in debug

3. connect to your kubernetes cluster with e.g. k9s and forward the remote debug port
4. configure your debugger
5. run the app in debug